# What does select 2 mean in a union sql statement?

Tags: sql

I have the following code which unions two select statements but the second select starts off as select 2.  What does this do?

> `select tax_type, sum(amount)
>   from bill_tax_tbl a (index multi), bill_summ_tbl b
>   where a.customer_no = @customer_no
>   and a.invoice_month = convert(tinyint,datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-1,convert(datetime,@date))))
>   and a.job = b.job and a.billing_sub_job = b.billing_sub_job
>   and b.job_group is null
>   group by tax_type
>   union
>   select 2, sum(amount)
>   from bill_tax_tbl a (index multi), bill_summ_tbl b
>   where a.customer_no = @customer_no
>   and tax_type = 1
>   and a.invoice_month = convert(tinyint,datepart(mm,dateadd(mm,-1,convert(datetime,@date))))
>   and a.job = b.job and a.billing_sub_job = b.billing_sub_job
>   and b.job_group is null`

Comment: It is setting `tax_type` equal to `2` in the rows returned by the second subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 is a value constant that will end up in the tax_type field.

Example
Given the table:

```
+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |
+===========+
| 'a' | 'b' |
| 'c' | 'd' |
+------------
```

Queried By:

```
SELECT a, b from table
UNION
SELECT 'y','z'
```

Would return:

```
+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |
+===========+
| 'a' | 'b' |
| 'c' | 'd' |
| 'y' | 'z' |
+------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.